# Including Identity User with Entity Framework doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity-3

I am having trouble including my Identity User in query results. Other entities are included just fine, no matter how many levels deep.

Here's the model I'm using.

```
Building * --- 1 City
     *            *
     |          /
     |         /
     1        1
ApplicationUser
```

And the context:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Building> Buildings { get; set; }
}
```

Both `Building` and `City` have these properties:

```
public Guid ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
```

The query I'm using to retrieve data:

```
var building = context.Buildings
    .Include(c => c.ApplicationUser)
    .Include(c => c.City)
    .Include(c => c.City.ApplicationUser)
    .First();
```

In the result City is populated just fine, however ApplicationUser is not.

Could this be a naming issue? I've already tried `UserId` / `User` and `AspNetUserId` / `AspNetUser` as property names without succes.

I'm using Migrations to create the database. The table name that gets created for users is AspNetUsers.

I'm using entity framework 7 beta 7, not sure if this applies to other versions as well.

These are the files generated by EF Migrations.

[ApplicationDbContextModelSnapshot.cs](http://pastebin.com/kT7tBpmc)

[20150929181902_Init.cs](http://pastebin.com/UDQC4agV)

[20150929181902_Init.Designer.cs](http://pastebin.com/qcqKDU3T)

(I noticed I forgot to include the Building > City relation when generating files for upload, but that shouldn't matter for the example)

Comment: This could be a bug in EF7. What doesyour `OnModelCreating` method look like?

Comment: Is that a typo? .Include(c => c.AspNetUser). Are they in the same context? Do you have a DbSet for ApplicationUser ?

Comment: @SteveGreene That was a typo, just cleared it up. They are in the same context. Users are in the DbSet - it's a property in IdentityDbContext.

Comment: @natemcmaster I'm also thinking it could be a bug. OnModelCreating is empty - I'm using what is created by migrations. I will upload the generated files now.

Comment: You mean reverse engineering, not migrations right? You will need at least one onmodelcreating statement to do the user relation since it doesn't follow convention.

Comment: I do mean migrations. This is done using code first. `IdentityDbContext` does have an OnModelCreating but I'm not inheriting it or anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally figured it out.

`ApplicationUser` inherits from `IdentityUser` which inherits from `IdentityUser<string>`. The generic type is used as the primary key, so a `string`!

I changed my `Guid` foreign key properties to `string`s and now everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

Just to help anyone who also have a similar issue. I was facing same thing, same scenario: My custom identity user has some related entities and using .Include was not working. None of them would come back. But they used to.

Turns out I had created a custom ApplicationUserStore to automatically include the entities I would normally always need when retrieving a User but I had only overridden FindByIdAsync method. When I tried to use FindByNameAsync no entity would come back, obviously. Just had to override this and the other Find methods.